# Вывод нескольких цифр в std::cout, каждая занимает несколько строк

Tags: c++

Задание курсовой:

[image: Определить класс хранения и визуального представления числ в «чёрточной форме»]

Собственно, написал все, но не могу сформировать строку, смог только реализовать  вывод сверху вниз, а как строкой, не пойму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть, кто-нибудь знает? Ниже привожу код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};
    void MumberToLine(int a)
    {
        string Temp;
        ostringstream convert;
        convert << a;
        Temp = convert.str();
        for(int i = 0; i < Temp.length(); i++)
        {
            switch(Temp[i])
            {
                case '0':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "    " << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        <<  " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    cout << "   " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "    " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        <<  "   " << endl;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        <<  " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    cout << "  " << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "    " << endl;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        << "|   " << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "    " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        <<  "   " << endl;
                    break;
                case '8':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl;
                    break;
                case '9':
                    cout << " __" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << "|  |" << endl
                        << " __ " << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << "   |" << endl
                        << " __" << endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass p;
    p.MumberToLine(1234567890);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@dr_zak](/users/23944/dr_zak)](/users/23944/dr_zak), обратите внимание, "рисунок" каждой цифры у Вас занимает 7 строк. Т.е. нужен внешний цикл, на каждой итерации которого выводится строка с соответствующем уровнем рисунка всех цифр числа и промежутками между ними.

И лучше эти рисунки не выводить в виде констант, а хранить в виде матрицы из 10 строк (по одной на цифру) и 7 столбцов (уровней).

Тогда выводить будет совсем просто

```
 int length = Temp.length();
 for (int level = 0; level < 7; level++) 
   for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) // цикл по цифрам числа
      cout << image[Temp[j] - '0'][level] << (j != length - 1 ? "  " : "\n");
```